# Why is this data.txt file deleted whenever I restart the program?

Tags: java, file, io, writer

I have a simple txt file that will save only 1 word, but whenever I restart the program everything inside the data.txt is deleted - I don't know why?

The whole class code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class InfoSaver {
    File data = new File("data.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    PrintStream writer;
    FileInputStream fis;
    DataInputStream reader;
    public void init() throws IOException{
        fos = new FileOutputStream(data);
        writer = new PrintStream(fos);
        fis = new FileInputStream(data);
        reader = new DataInputStream(fis);

    }
    public void writeData(String info) {
        writer.println(info);

    }
    public String readData() throws IOException{
        return reader.readLine();
    }
    public void close() throws IOException{
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: because you overwrite the existing file with a new one whenever you run your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not appending new information to the file, you're overwriting it.

Anytime you just open it in the

> fos = new FileOutputStream(data);

command, it gets emptied, no matter if you have saved anything inside it or not.

Answer (score 5):

To add to an existing file instead of overwriting it, use FileOutputStream's constructor that lets you open it in append mode.

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(data, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of this line:

```
 fos = new FileOutputStream(data);
```

[This version of the constructor of FileOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) will overwite the file, but you could use [this version](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29):

```
public FileOutputStream(File file,
                        boolean append)
                 throws FileNotFoundException
```

You'd have to specify that you want to append to the file by setting the `append` field to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FileOutputStream` is overwriting your file. If you want to append to the end of the file you need to specify that:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(data, true);
```

When you encounter unexpected behavior it's a good idea to check the API to ensure the functions you're calling are doing what you expect.  [Here is the API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) for the `FileOutputStream` constructor.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please be sure to accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer, and also upvote any helpful answer.